# I can't compute the sqrt of a 0<= number <1

Tags: c, sqrt

I have written a program that computes an estimated value of sqrt(x):

**Explanation of the code below**

I'm trying to find the nearest number (S) to (x) which can be represented as  **S=sqrt*sqrt**, keep looping until `fabs(_sqrt - sqrt) >= 1e-8` is not correct that means that sqrt and _sqrt are very close.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double val, min, max; 
    double sqrt;
    double S, _sqrt;
    int cnt = 0;

    // enter an argument,

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: sqrt < number >\n");
        return 1;
    }
     val = fabs (atof (argv[1]));
        min = 0;//minimum 
        max = sqrt = val;//maximum 
        _sqrt = 1;
        //1e-8 = 10^(-8) = 0.00000001
        while (fabs(_sqrt - sqrt) >= 1e-8) {
            _sqrt = sqrt;//keep the old sqrt
            sqrt = (max + min) / 2;
            S = sqrt * sqrt;
            printf("test n(%d)\tsqrt(%lf) = %.6lf\n",++cnt,val, sqrt);
                if (S>val){
                    max = sqrt;//setting max to the current sqrt
                } else{
                    min = sqrt;//setting min to the current sqrt
                }//end else
        }//end while
        puts("");
        puts("\t====================================================");
        printf ("\tfinal value.\tsqrt(%lf) = %.6lf\n", val, sqrt);
        puts("\t====================================================");
    return 0;
}//end main()
```

**the output**

```
[ar.lnx@host square-root] $ ./sqrt 2        
test n(1)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.000000
test n(2)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.500000
test n(3)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.250000
test n(4)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.375000
test n(5)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.437500
test n(6)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.406250
test n(7)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.421875
test n(8)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414062
test n(9)       sqrt(2.000000) = 1.417969
test n(10)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.416016
test n(11)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.415039
test n(12)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414551
test n(13)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414307
test n(14)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414185
test n(15)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414246
test n(16)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414215
test n(17)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414200
test n(18)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414207
test n(19)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414211
test n(20)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414213
test n(21)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
test n(22)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
test n(23)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414213
test n(24)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
test n(25)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
test n(26)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
test n(27)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
test n(28)      sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214

        ====================================================
        final value.    sqrt(2.000000) = 1.414214
        ====================================================
```

but it works only for every x>=1, if i want to calculate the sqrt of 0.5 or 0.254 or 0.1... it not works!

```
[ar.lnx@host square-root] $ ./sqrt1 0.5
test n(1)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.250000
test n(2)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.375000
test n(3)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.437500
test n(4)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.468750
test n(5)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.484375
test n(6)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.492188
test n(7)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.496094
test n(8)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.498047
test n(9)       sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499023
test n(10)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499512
test n(11)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499756
test n(12)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499878
test n(13)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499939
test n(14)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499969
test n(15)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499985
test n(16)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499992
test n(17)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499996
test n(18)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499998
test n(19)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.499999
test n(20)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
test n(21)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
test n(22)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
test n(23)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
test n(24)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
test n(25)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
test n(26)      sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000

        ====================================================
        final value.    sqrt(0.500000) = 0.500000
        ====================================================
```

Can someone help me understand what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: You're setting the max value to lower than the value you're trying to find.

Comment: Once you have fixed your code, you can play with recursion by creating a function to get the next estimate. Then instead of looping, call the next estimate function with the new max and min and the old estimate. exit if the new estimate is within the limit (passing that back up through the recursion). While this is less efficient, it can teach you about using recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your conversion logic only works if `val > 1`

Note the way you test the `sqrt(.5)` Since when `val == 0.5` you get `S = val * val` which is `0.25`. This resets `min` to `0.25`  Since `sqrt = (max + min) / 2;` and the initial `max` is `val` (0.5) you can never get past `0.5`.

You will have to determine that since your initial `val` is less than 1, you want your initial `max` to be 1 so that your average is `val < sqrt < 1`

If you do this, then you should converge on the correct value.

I do not have access to a C compiler at this time. However, by initial inspection the first average is `1.5/2 == .75` which resets max. The new average is `1.25/2 == .625` which resets min You should then continue until you converge on the correct value.

FYI you can also use the contents of the while loop as a different function in order to teach yourself recursion. That is, instead of looping through the while, if S > lim {call the new estimate function} once it falls through the recursion, it will pass the final estimate back up to the initial calling function.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're initializing `max` to `val`.  For numbers less than 1, the square root will be *greater* than the number, not less.  For instance, for 0.5 the square root is 0.707...  A simple fix would be to initialize `max` to 1 if `val` is less than 1.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your value of `max`, which has to be greater or equal the expected result. If your input is less than `1.0`, the result is greater than the input and less than `1.0`. Your value for `max` has to be `1.0` at least. Adapt your code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double val, min, max; 
    double sqrt;
    double S, _sqrt;
    int cnt = 0;

    // enter an argument,

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: sqrt < number >\n");
        return 1;
    }
    val = fabs (atof (argv[1]));       

    if ( val < 1.0 )
    {
        min = val;        
        max = sqrt = 1.0; // if val < 1.0 result is greater than val but less than 1.0
    }
    else
    {
        min = 0;          //minimum 
        max = sqrt = val; //maximum
    } 

    do
    {
        _sqrt = sqrt;//keep the old sqrt
        sqrt = (max + min) / 2;
        S = sqrt * sqrt;
        printf("test n(%d)\tsqrt(%lf) = %.6lf\n",++cnt,val, sqrt);
        if (S>val){
            max = sqrt;//setting max to the current sqrt
        } else{
            min = sqrt;//setting min to the current sqrt
        }//end else
    }
    while ( fabs(_sqrt - sqrt) >= 1e-8); //1e-8 = 10^(-8) = 0.00000001

    puts("");
    puts("\t====================================================");
    printf ("\tfinal value.\tsqrt(%lf) = %.6lf\n", val, sqrt);
    puts("\t====================================================");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see where in your code the variable cycle is defined. Nor is is reset within the do ... while loop.